# Prevent Button Click On Press Enter Button From Parent Element

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to prevent click event when i am coming from parent to child element. I am trying to use Kendo Grid with Kendo Pager.

Here is Example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gjgypw-qmo6s6?file=app/app.component.ts

```
<ng-template kendoPagerTemplate let-totalPages="totalPages" let-currentPage="currentPage">
    <!-- This button should not be clicked when coming from parent element -->
    <button kendoGridFocusable (click)="sample()">Sample</button>
    <kendo-pager-prev-buttons></kendo-pager-prev-buttons>
    <kendo-slider
        kendoGridFocusable
        [showButtons]="false"
        tickPlacement="none"
        [max]="totalPages"
        [min]="1"
        (valueChange)="sliderChange($event)"
        [value]="currentPage">
    </kendo-slider>
    <kendo-pager-next-buttons></kendo-pager-next-buttons>
    <input
        kendoGridFocusable
        class="k-textbox k-input k-rounded-md"
        type="number"
        [value]="pageSize"
        (change)="onPageSizeChange($event.target.value)" />
    <kendo-pager-info></kendo-pager-info>
</ng-template>
```

The button is getting clicked when i am pressing `enter button` to get inside and access the buttons. If you see example, whenever we are pager, we need to press `enter` key to get accessible for all buttons inside it and `Esc` to get outside. Button should be clickable but should not be clickable when entering inside it.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried catching the enter event and --> event.stopPropagation

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).